# Why Does Python print() function return EOL?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to use the Python print() function with a multi-line string literal --
I am using a vertical ellipsis to indicate multiple lines, not content, of the string literal.

```
print("Here is the data table: 
        .
        .
        .                   ")
```

Why am I getting EOL while scanning string literal error.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `"""` or `'''` for multiline [string literals](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Edit: as pointed out by @lvc in the comments, since you have parens around the string, you can still use the single quotes, you just have to start and end each line with `"`.

Comment: You don't need to end each line with a `\` here, since its in brackets anyway.

Comment: Ok, apparently I didn't escape my backslash, and now its too late to edit it - that was meant to say "You don't need to end with \ here", etc.

Comment: @lvc: edited answer to reflect your comment. I still think triple-quotes are the more-readable option, but either way works.

Comment: @bernie slight correction to your edit: s/end/start and end/ . One major reason to prefer this over triple quotes, btw, is it lets you keep the strings lined up after the `(`, without putting extra whitespace in the string itself.

Answer (score 1):

A string beginning with a single quote (either " or ') in python cannot span multiple lines. You must use a triple-quote string. For example:

```
print("""Here is the data table:
    ....
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using """ instead of " while delimiting the string:

```
print """
multiline string

...
"""
```

Comment: He seems to be using python 3x print should be a function not a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1. Use triple quotes as suggested by the rest. The annoying thing is that the first line of the string doesn't line up with the rest in the code.
2. Use backslashes, pluses and multiple strings like this:

   print ("Here is the data table:"
        ""
        "...."
        ""
    )
3. Use newline characters (`\n`) in the string like this:

   print ("Here is the data table:\n...\n\n\n")

Comment: You don't need to use `+` to combine string literals - if you have two next to each other, Python parses them as a single string. And you don't need the backslashes either, since its in brackets.

Comment: You're right about that. I still use the print statement instead of the function most of the time so that's why.